# How to make task schedular to execute batch script (which executes a .exe) in foreground even if windows PC restarts? This should be automatic

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am executing a script named Add_Schedular.bat which adds a task scheduler with name RTDAS_Watchdog automatically. `RTDAS_Watchdog` runs `RTDAS_Watchdog.bat` after each 1 min. `RTDAS_Watchdog.bat` does work of checking whether `RTDAS_Manager.exe` is running continuously. If `RTDAS_Manager.exe` is not running it just restarts it.

Add_Schedular.bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CURDIR=%CD%
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "RTDAS_Watchdog" /V1 /tr "%CURDIR%\RTDAS_Watchdog.bat"
```

RTDAS_Watchdog.bat file:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=RTDAS_Manager.exe
set CURDIR=%~dp0
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND
echo Not running
"%CURDIR%\%EXE%" -shell
goto FIN
:FOUND
echo Running
:FIN
```

Problem is when windows PC is restarted, RTDAS_Manager.exe goes in background. I want this .exe to always execute in foreground even after PC is restarted without user login to PC.

Comment: With what you have told us, we can only guess. Mine is that `%CD%` should be `%~dp0`. Then `"%CURDIR%\RTDAS_Watchdog.bat"` should be `"%CURDIR%RTDAS_Watchdog.bat"`.

Comment: Doing above changes wont solve problem of .exe running in background when PC is restarted. When user is logged in, my .exe file is executed in foreground. Problem is when PC is restarted, RTDAS_Manager.exe goes in background.

Comment: Solutions are placed in the answer area. Until you've provided sufficient information for somebody to offer an answer, you'll receive only comments, (with guesses, and general advice). Additionally, when working with the Task Scheduler, depending upon the configuration of the task, the current directory is not always what you think it is, _(it is very often `C:\Windows\System32`)_. Given that an assumption could be made that `%CD%` and therefore `%CURDIR%` resolves to `C:\Windows\System32` and as a result the fully qualified batch file would need to be `C:\Windows\System32\RTDAS_Watchdog.bat`.

Comment: I have made suggested changes in Add_Schedular.bat file. But problem was not solved. .exe is yet running in background when system is restarted.

Comment: Any other suggestion about my problem?